# How to dynamically change user roles in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to change user role on the fly based on specific data stored in the session. So on each request the authorization systems can check if the user can access some resource. I don't want store roles in a database. The role would be data dependent.

For example, a user that is `admin` of a real state company can manage his agents and properties, but an `agent` can manage only properties assigned to him. Also a `buyer` can view data of properties that he has purchased.

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of what you have got so far?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [This blog post](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-creating-dynamic-roles-using-roleinterface/), it shows how you can add user dependent roles.  You can modify the part where he actually sets the role name.

I would make a few modifications to this method though

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return new UserDependentRole($this);
    }
}
```

And in the `UserDependentRole` class, have this instead:

```
public function getRole()
{
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_' . strtoupper($this->user->getUsername());
    //... make an array of all the roles you want the user to have

    return $roles;
}
```

I'm sure if you read the article you will figure out how to do it.